# DocuSign embedded envelope correct returnUrl not working

Tags: docusignapi

I am using an embedded envelope correct view in my website. I have attempted to define the returnUrl, but the view seems to always return to the DocuSign console. I am still using a demo account, so I'm thinking this may be a feature that's only available on production accounts?

I'm posting to

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/views/correct
```

and passing the following fields:

```
 {
      "returnUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
      "supressNavigation": "true"
 }
```

I get a successful response and the provided URL works correctly to edit an envelope, it just still shows the navigation and doesn't forward to the specified return URL after editing. Are these features available on a demo account and if so, do I need to enable them somewhere?

Comment: I get the same result as you, both in Dev and in Prod. i.e., despite the fact that my request body specifies a returnUrl, the user always gets sent to the DocuSign "Sent Items" page (of the DocuSign web console) after they submit the Envelope correction. Seems like perhaps this is a bug, but someone from DocuSign will need to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too am seeing the same results (i.e. returnUrl and suppressNavigation are ignored with the embedded envelope correction api call).

Bug has been logged with DocuSign, for internal reference this is bug `TRI-707`.  I'll update this post and add comments as more info becomes available.

Comment: in my returnUrl, I am passing two query parameters, but after signing the contract, one of the query parameter passed is missing. 
I am passing returnUrl=https://example.com/options?param1=a&param2=b.
But after successful signing I am getting
https://example.com/options?param1=a&event=signed_successuly
param2 is gone missing.